# when is it a good idea to reference a slice indice expression?

Tags: go

When using a slice, I struggle to find a good case where creating a reference to an indice expression is a good idea.

Because slices, via the built in function `append`, are implemented using particular mechanisms, their backing array can be modified at runtime, and while this is considered a good thing, i below code there is a non obvious mistake.

But in below example, that is totally correct from a compiler point of view, it is extremely confusing for most programmers, Yet, this is allowed by the language specification.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    broken()
    fmt.Printf("------------\n")
    lessbroken()
}
func broken() {
    var lump []int
    var lumpp []*int

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        lump = append(lump, int(i))
        lumpp = append(lumpp, &lump[i])
    }
    *(lumpp[0]) = 5
    fmt.Printf("lump[0]: %#v\n", lump[0])
}

func lessbroken() {
    lump := make([]int, 8, 8)
    var lumpp []*int

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        lump[i] = i
        lumpp = append(lumpp, &lump[i])
    }
    *(lumpp[0]) = 5
    fmt.Printf("lump[0]: %#v\n", lump[0])
}
```

outputs

```
lump[0]: 0
------------
lump[0]: 5
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rl5O9ecp7Zq

I struggled to understand the post [Why does pointer assignment cause variable assignment to not always stick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047263/why-does-pointer-assignment-cause-variable-assignment-to-not-always-stick) now i want to figure out if i should consider this as bad practice or if there is something, i probably, miss..

Comment: "Because slices are mostly automatically managed by the runtime, their memory adresses can be modified at runtime" Both, antecedent and consequent are wrong: Neither are slices "managed by the runtime" (at least not more than any other variable in Go) nor  can their "addresses ... be modified" (as no variable's address can be modified). During slice growth a _new_ slice (with a new address and a new backing  array may be returned, but the old slice and its address are unchanged.

Comment: OK, the precisions are worthy. Though, i am still not convinced when you say that slices are not, somehow, managed by the runtime.

Comment: It is like saying that int32 variables are managed by the runtime. Yes they are in the sense of the runtime providing memory for the variable and GCs it once unreachable but as such it is a non-information as the same holds true for everything in Go: int32, complex126, chan uint8 and function closures to name a few. A slice is not more "managed by the runtime" than a bool is.

Comment: I think the culprit is in `If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array.`. ref: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices Where the "thing" creating the difficulty i illustrated is the `append` built in function. But `append` is the way to work with a slice, and goes hand to hand with this type. To approach the problem in a first approximation i say it's ok...

Comment: ... to generalize with the word `slice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful about storing pointers to elements of a slice, because a slice is a view over an array, and what you are really storing is pointers to the elements of the underlying array. Even though the array remains valid, the slice may allocate a new array when elements are appended to it.

A common way to deal with this problem is to use a slice of pointers in the first place. That way, even though the slice may allocate a new array the actual data pointed to by the array elements are still valid, and can be dereferenced without a problem.

Another way to deal with this is to pre-allocate the slice, or populate it first and then deal with pointers to its elements later when there are no more append operations remaining. This is what you already showed in the second part of your example.

Whether or not this is bad practice depends on the situation. If there is a chance that someone else will later come and modify the logic, the first option is safer in my opinion.

Comment: Fully agree with the post, especially with `A common way to deal with this problem is to use a slice of pointers in the first place.`

Comment: out of curiosity, what has gone wrong in this post (which is just about that question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095052/slice-element-not-updated-in-go/65095501 ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I suppose you're asking about your answer? I see nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: yes i was confused about the accepted answer and the many downvotes i got, I dont care about the downvotes, that just did not make sense to me and wondered if i was missing something obvious, but there was no additional comments to explain those downvotes. hence my question here. Thank you for confirming it is just a system failure.